# Send data between screen using Getx Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-getx

I am able to send id of specific index from product page to product detail page but it sets the arguments as null when i select the images from gallery

Comment: Please  add some code and add exactly what you need

Answer (score 0):

TO PASS ID:
You need to use `Get.parameters` instead of `Get.arguments`

So when navigating to the product details page add id to parameters:

```
Get.toNamed('details-page-name', parameters: {'id': product.id});
```

And when you are in `details-page-name` route, you can use this id by:

```
id = Get.parameters['id'];
```

Comment: @HiraKauchha accept it as an answer if you found it helpful

Answer (score 0):

For me i used only normal things

```
Get.off(()=>SecondPage(id : id));
```

then for the  Secondpage

```
  class SecondPage extends StatlessWidget{

final String? id;

SecondPage({this.id});

}
```

Comment: Actually, this is not in GetX as the question says

Comment: yeah but it depend on you to use parameter or arguments or something like this anyway am just giving some thing might help or other ways.

Comment: yeah this is not in GetX but simple tricks he does help me out and @SajadAbdollahi brother thanks you too but that doesn't help me in my case