# how to let get.back take some argument

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

my wish is when user hits back button on Page B to jump back to Page A, `Get.back()` is activated, but it should take an argument such as newCreatedId, I found something like `Get.back(result: [newCreatedId]);`, but I didn't find tutorial how to let Page A get this argument, plz help me thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [flutter passing multiple data with getx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64906620/flutter-passing-multiple-data-with-getx)

Comment: also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69187574/send-data-through-arguments-with-getx

Comment: ALSO, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68780829/send-data-between-screen-using-getx-flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `Get.back()` with the result property is exactly what you need, and I will explain it to you:

so using `Getx`, when you're trying to navigate to another route, we usually just call `Get.to()` directly:

```
Get.to(MyOtherScreen());
```

right?

in order to get some data from the `MyOtherScreen()`, it's different a little bit, instead of calling just `Get.to()` directly we need to assign its call to a variable like this:

```
var futureData = Get.to(MyOtherScreen());
```

even if you assign it to a variable like this, it still works fine and navigates to `MyOtherScreen()` as expected.

after navigating, we are now in the `MyOtherScreen()`, after the user did what he needs to do on that page and wants to pop/back of that page with some data, you need to call:

```
Get.back(result: theDataFromMyOtherScreen);
```

**what this will do:**
it will close the `MyOtherScreen()` page and will store the `theDataFromMyOtherScreen` inside of the first variable where we assigned to it the `Get.to()`.

so the result after popping the page will be:

```
var futureData = Get.to(MyOtherScreen()); // futureData == theDataFromMyOtherScreen
```

now if you try to print it as example:

```
print(futureData); // will print the value of theDataFromMyOtherScreen
```

and every time you do the same routing process, it will store new data in that variable.

to recap:
the `Get.to()` we called inside the variable navigates with us to the other page, and `Get.back()` will return us to the previous page with the value stored in the `result` property, so you can think of them that they are linked.

Comment: Hi Gwhyyy, thank you very much for you detailed explanation, Im learning flutter and getx, now I guess I understand more about it! Have a nice day.